# Extracting column from DataTable

Tags: java, cucumber, integration-testing

I have scenario like below:

```
  Scenario: do something interesting
    Given the following users
      | first_name | last_name | address |
      | John       | Doe       | add1    |
      | Jane       | Doe       | add2    |
```

How can I extract list of elements, as example: from **first_name** column.

I've tried to use **cucumber.api.DataTable**, but looks like it uses for other purposes.

I can extract only rows and then manage it as I want.

Comment: do you need the rows or only the columns? if you only need the columns, then you should rotate your table. There is no direct way to only access columns

Answer (score 3):

The most readable option in my opinion would be the `asMaps` method, that way you are independent of the ordering of columns:

```
@Given("^the following users$")
public void the_following_users(DataTable table) {
    for (Map<String, String> row : table.asMaps(String.class, String.class)) {
        System.out.println(row.get("first_name"));
    }
}
```

Extracting a single column of a `DataTable` is not part of its api, so you would have to implement that yourself in java.

Answer (score 0):

i'm guessing you just want a List, but since you're using raw jdbc calls, you still have to traverse the ResultSet.  you would need to craft your query to just return the one column and then extract each single item row into your result List object.

now if you were using JPA, you could fetch the result into a List by crafting your query to just return the one column and JPA would automatically unwrap it into a List (or List for other types like Date or Integer).

Answer (score 0):

Please try this code, it will give you the value under "first_name" column. If you have multiple rows, then use this code in loop

```
`@Given("^the following users$")
public void the_following_users(DataTable records) 
{
    for (Map<String, String> row : records.asMaps(String.class, String.class)) 
    { 
        System.out.println(row.get("first_name").intern());
    }
}`
```